# Как добавить Яндекс.Браузер в качестве браузера для отладки в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Начал заниматься изучением языка Dart и в том числе фреймворка Flutter, и возник такой вопрос: можно ли как-то "руками" добавить Яндекс.Браузер как устройство для запуска Flutter-приложения? Потому что сам по себе он не обнаруживается ни с помощью Android Studio, ни через командную строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это не сложно, опишу процесс для Android Studio для mac OS, но думаю на других OS будет то же самое. Приложу скриншоты для удобства, чтобы было понятнее где искать.

1. Откройте **Preferences**.
2. Зайдите в категорию **Tools**.
3. Выберите вкладку **Web browsers**.

Как это окно выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]:

Далее в дропдауне **Default Browser** вместо **System Default** выберите нужный вариант.

Также можно пойти другим путем и просто изменить **System Default** браузер в настройках OS, тогда в студии ничего не придется менять.

---

**UPD:**
Eсли способ выше не работает, можно задеплоить на локальный веб сервер. Для этого просто запустите команду `flutter run -d web-server`. После запуска в терминале будет ссылка к веб серверу, вбейте ее в подходящий для вас браузер и вы увидите ваше приложение.

Но хочу заметить, что флаттер заточен под Chrome и некоторые фичи дебаггинга могут не работать в других браузерах.

Comment: Хммм, у меня браузер по умолчанию стоит Yandex, и так как вы сказали я поменял. Однако Android Studio всё ещё отказывается видеть его и даёт возможность запускать только в Edge. Может, это из-за того, что я пытаюсь запустить проект приложения Flutter?

Comment: @МаксимТутункин да, действительно, проверил, с флаттером не прокатило таким способом. Попробовал другой способ через терминал, сработало, дополнил ответ

Comment: Да, действительно заработало) Спасибо большое